# Why is finite rank necessary here? - Dummit & Foote 10.3.13

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, free-modules

Problem statement: "Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $F$ be a free $R$-module of finite rank. Prove the following isomorphism of $R$-modules: Hom$_R(F,R) \simeq F.$"

My proof relies on the fact that for any element $\phi \in \text{Hom}_R(F,R)$ we can map it to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \phi(a_i)a_i$ for $\{a_1,\ a_2,\ \dots,\ a_n\}$ a basis for $F$. But shouldn't you also be able to use infinite sums here instead, if the basis were infinite? Or does something break in the infinite case?

(And for any given element of $F$, all but finitely many basis elements should have a coefficient of 0 according to the definition of free modules in the text, but that shouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: I'm not sure on this subject, so it may be necessary.  It may also not be necessary but included as a simplifying assumption to allow for easier proofs,  this is often done when introducing a subject.  For instance,  I was asked in my first graduate linear algebra class to show that in a finite dimensional normed vector space, the set of invertible operators is open.  This is true in the infinite dimensional case also, but there's a lot easier proofs in the finite one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, with the given hypotheses you cannot use infinite sums here. No object in this construction has a topology so there's no way to define convergence of such a sum. And in fact the statement is false in the infinite rank case: for example if $R = \mathbb{Q}$ and $F = \bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Q}$ is a countable-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, then $\text{Hom}_R(F, R) \cong \mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable-dimensional.

Comment: Hm. Why can't we think of these formal sums of basis elements as being equivalent to tuples, which are well-defined when infinite, as infinite sequences? Even without a topology on them, I mean. (Or do you in fact need a topology to define infinite sequences?)

Comment: @BabylonianTriple: the tuples are perfectly well-defined, that's not the issue. The issue is that there is no way to make sense of the infinite sum $\sum \phi(a_i) a_i$ as in your argument.

Comment: Ah, even though it's basically a formal sum? Okay, thank you.

Comment: @BabylonianTriple The problem is: how do you associate to your formal sum an element from F? Remember that what you want to do is find a map from $Hom_R(F,R)$ to $F$, but your formal infinite sum doesn't live in $F$.

Comment: @BabylonianTriple: think of what you would do with the formal sum, in $\mathbb R$, $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}(-1)^n n.$$

Comment: @Hagamena Maybe I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, but isn't $F$ exactly just a collection of formal finite sums with formal algebraic properties, but without any real $\textit{meaning}$? Like, they may as well be tuples, and it would make no difference, no?

Comment: @BabylonianTriple: yes, exactly, they are formal *finite* sums. You are trying to take a formal *infinite* sum here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So it's simply that $F$'s definition doesn't allow for formal infinite sums, even if it had an infinite basis?

Comment: @BabylonianTriple: yes, but it's worse than that; there's just no way to define an $R$-module using formal infinite sums *at all*. If $M$ is an $R$-module and $m \in M$ is an element then what is the infinite sum $m + m + m + \dots $?

Answer (score 3):

I think finite-dimensionality is needed, even for the simple case that $R$ is a field and $F$ is a vector space over $R$. This is because $\operatorname{hom}_{R}(F,R)$ is the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) to $F$, and an infinite-dimensional vector space is never isomorphic to its dual.